# Additional Command Line Arguments for Running Program in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, ide, codeblocks

Many IDEs allow you to add some custom command line arguments which are used when the IDE runs your program after compilation. E.g my program is `pro_ext_changer.exe`, I'd like to add a `--backup` option when running it:

```
pro_ext_changer.exe --backup
```

I haven't found a way to do this in Code::Blocks. How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Project] → [Set program's arguments…]

I didn't know that but I just fired up Code::Blocks, which I've only toyed with, and I looked around.